# android frames per second - how optimize and is it because a phone?

Tags: android, optimization, unity-game-engine

I have small game project. It looks fine, works fine, but when I started it today at Android with fps counter - I have just 10 fps o.O

What are ways to optimize? What should I verify?

My app have:
menu panel with two buttons
game panel with view from phone camera
some other panels with some graphics/buttons (never more than 5 per panel)
No animation, no complicated scripts. At my computer it has about 60 fps.
I'm doing it in Unity3D.
I'm using NGUI+tk2d, I have one/two drawcalls per panel. I'm disabling panels which aren't using. 
I'm not using Update function to often - just for "fps counter" and... that's all. 
I'm using atlases for all graphics.

So - what more should I verify? I'm really confused. Can it be because of my phone have something wrong with system? Or it's problem with app?

I will be really grateful for your suggestions.

Comment: what phone exactly? how old is it? Try a minimalistic app (just a background sprite or model) to see what the performance is in that case.

Comment: What happens if you disable/remove all your NGUI stuff? does it still give you 10fps?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, LG L9, but I have big mess there. Good idea to try with simple app.

Comment: @user2320445, how I wrote - 1 drawcall. At one panel I have 2 drawcalls.

Comment: did you used profiler to see where problem is coming from

Comment: @user2320445 I don't have pro version. And how can I use profiler if problem is at smarphone? I was trying it some time ago at computer, but I didn't understand how.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I've tried with simplier app - it's not phone problem. I don't know where to looking for mistakes, now :(

Comment: Neither do we without seeing the code and scene setup.